# If Adam and Eve have not sin, would there be any population on earth?

Tags: genesis, adam-and-eve, fall-of-man

In the garden of Eden, Adam and Eve were innocent until they both ate the fruit of knowledge and evil and the curtain of their innocence were exposed and realised that they were naked. Having said these, would there be any population on earth if they have not eaten the fruit which is the knowledge of good and evil?

Bible commentary in Genesis - Eprem the Syrian A.D. 373

> [ Gen1:28 ] Because they were blessed on this earth, it is as if this dwelling spot had been prepared for them prior to their sin. For although they had not yet sinned God knew that they were about to sin.

> "Be fruitful and multiply and fill," not Paradise but "the earth," [ Gen1:28 ] and "have dominion over the fish of the sea and the birds and over all the beasts." [ Gen1:28 ] But how was Adam to rule over the fish of the sea unless he were in proximity to the sea? And how was he to rule over the birds that fly throughout every region unless his descendants were to dwell in every region? And how was Adam to rule over every beast of the earth unless his offspring inhabited the entire earth?

> Although Adam was created and was blessed to rule over the earth and over everything that was created and blessed in [ the earth ], God had indeed made him to dwell within Paradise. God truly manifested His fore-knowledge in His blessings and manifested His grace in the place in which He caused Adam to dwell. Lest it be said that Paradise was not created for [ Adam's ] sake, God made him dwell there in Paradise. And lest it be said that God did not know that Adam would sin, He blessed him on this earth. And everything with which God blessed Adam preceded the transgression of the commandment, lest by the transgression of him who had been blessed, the blessings of Him who gives blessing be withheld and the world be turned back into nothing on account of the folly of that one for whose sake everything had been created.

> Within Paradise, therefore, God did not bless Adam because that place and all that was in it is blessed. But God blessed him on the earth first so that by the blessing with which [ His ] grace blessed beforehand, the curse of the earth, which was about to be cursed by [ His ] justice, might [ thus ] be diminished. But even though it was a blessing of promise, in that it was fulfilled after his expulsion from Paradise, it was, nevertheless, His grace that was effected, for on that same day, God made Adam dwell in the garden, clothed him with glory and made him ruler over all the trees of Paradise.

Comment: Why would there not be people on the earth given the commandment to populate the earth (Gen 1:28)?

Comment: Hypothetical questions like this aren't allowed unless directed at a particular denomination.

Comment: OT, and anyway clearly "yes", but also note that the significance of the GoE isn't that the rest of the Earth was barren or something, but that that is where the Tree of Life was located.

Answer (score 1):

I believe so. God created man and woman male and female before the fall. He didn't create only men before the fall, then after the fall, say "Well, we need more of you, so let's make you so that you can reproduce!"

Also, as @agarza pointed out in his comment, God says in Gn 1:28, before the fall,

> “Be fruitful and multiply, and fill the earth and subdue it; and have dominion over the fish of the sea and over the birds of the air and over every living thing that moves upon the earth.”

Thus, God must have planned for men and women to multiply before the fall.